# Preciso fazer um auto preenchimento em um input

Tags: javascript, jquery

Boa tarde, gostaria de ajuda para fazer um auto preenchimento

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('nightlife_drug_quantity')[0];
```

preciso que complete sempre isto com o número 50.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Só adicionar value="50" direto no html. Se quiser que nao seja editavel só adicionar um readonly. Ou por js, como o do comentário anterior.
Exemplo:

```
<input type="text" class="nightlife_drug_quantity" value="50" readonly>
```